# How to access XSD metadata while parsing an XML instance document

Tags: xml, xsd

In my application I need to parse an XML file against an XSD. The XSD file will store some metadata against specific XSD nodes, which will need to be accessed in my application while an XML file is being parsed against this XSD. Basically, the metadata is information which allows me to link tag values from the input XMLs to some application-specific context. For example, my XSD metadata might store a mapping of a tag to a database table name, etc.

I have been searching the net for examples of how to achieve the above. I came across xsd:appinfo as a way of storing metadata in an XSD file, but there seems to be no way of accessing the appinfo (or any other XSD tag) while an XML is being parsed against this XSD. Fro example, if I use a Xerces SAX parser, I would ideally want the appinfo to be given to me in the startElement() callback. However, I do not see any way in SAX or DOM parsing to achieve this.

Is the above requirement not possible to achieve?

Note: I am considering using either C/C++ or Python for the parser library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is that you want to use the **Grammar** interfaces...

### Apache Xerces2 Java

Xerces2-J implements the [XML Schema API](http://www.w3.org/Submission/2004/SUBM-xmlschema-api-20040122/) for XSD grammars.

You can get a [Grammar](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xni/org/apache/xerces/xni/grammars/Grammar.html) by in various ways.  What's best will depend upon your needs.  Read the [FAQ for Caching & Preparsing Grammars](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-grammars.html).  Also, consult the sample, [xni.XMLGrammarBuilder](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/samples-xni.html#XMLGrammarBuilder) for code examples dealing with Grammars.

You can then cast your Grammar to the [XSGrammar](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xni/org/apache/xerces/xni/grammars/XSGrammar.html) interface, which has a [toXSModel()](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xni/org/apache/xerces/xni/grammars/XSGrammar.html) method, which returns a [XSModel](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xs/org/apache/xerces/xs/XSModel.html), which has a [getAnnotations()](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xs/org/apache/xerces/xs/XSModel.html#getAnnotations()) method.

### Apache Xerces C++

For [SAXParser](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classSAXParser.html), see [getRootGrammar()](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classSAXParser.html#af8e72a2c6923576dc77888e6febdaea5) or  [getGrammar()](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classSAXParser.html#a25b2fb8df7d0f5eae8c184116a9c0f86).

For [XercesDOMParser](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classXercesDOMParser.html), see [getRootGrammar()](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classXercesDOMParser.html#a4e1aeb7bc63d4edf95ade1d168c60f62) or [getGrammar()](https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classXercesDOMParser.html#a84fb7f2836b7de3724b623e8c96e5eaf).

Comment: Thank you, this answer is very helpful. I had come across the getGrammar() and getRootGrammar() APIs while reading through the SAX API documentation, but I was not sure if this would serve my purpose. I'll try out these APIs and post an update.

Answer (score -1):

There are utilities that generate code for C++ classes in accordance with the XML Schema. For example, CodeSynthesis, Codalogic, Altova, etc. Using them, you get a model with strongly typed classes derived from the metadata.